# How to decode openssl enc'd data with salted password?

Tags: web-scraping, openssl

```
$ curl -s 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/MSFT/profile?p=MSFT' | awk -v ORS= 'match($0, /^ *root[.]App[.]main = (.*);$/, a) { print a[1] }' | jq -r .context.dispatcher.stores > /tmp/tmp.txt
$ file /tmp/tmp.txt
/tmp/tmp.txt: openssl enc'd data with salted password, base64 encoded
```

How can I decode the above data?

Comment: If it actually used OpenSSL-compatible encryption and isn't camoflage for something else, you need to know which cipher+mode (or try all, there's only about a hundred); which old-style PBKDF hash was used (but there's only two likely possibilities for commandline and one for php or nodejs) or if the new `-pbkdf2` option in 1.1.1 up was used and if so whether `-iter` was changed and what to; and most importantly know or guess the password used, which is very likely designed to be impossible in this universe. But this is not programming or development.

Comment: Could you post the commands so that I can try them? If the webpage can use the data, then there must be a way to decipher the data. If a password is needed, why it can not be found on the webpage?

Comment: See https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-enc.html . But what evidence do you have the webpage deciphers the data? Usually data like this is simply sent back to the server on a subsequent request and the _server_ has the password (or key) to decipher it, as well as knowing the relevant parameters (cipher&PBKDF).

Comment: I don't have evidence. I didn't know that this could be sent back to servers to decipher it. But what is the point of encrypting the data given all the data that users should see are already displayed in the browser?

Comment: (All the) data users should see is sent in clear; the server encrypts data that it does NOT want the user to see, but wants to (have sent back and) use in processing subsequent requests.